# Glossary input filter saving to node_revisions

Tags: 6, input-formats

I have been using the [Glossary](http://drupal.org/project/glossary) module and it has been working great. I add  `"ADSL"` into a node and if a glossary definition exists, on render it converts it to `"<acronym title="Asymmetric Digital Subscriber Line">ADSL</acronym>"`.

However, today I noticed it has started putting the glossary term markup into the node content (saving in the database table node_revisions). When I edit the node again, it no longer contains "ADSL"; it contains the full markup generated by the Glossary input filter (`<acronym title="Asymmetric Digital Subscriber Line">ADSL</acronym>`).

As far as I am aware, the data is saved straight to the database before any input filter should touch it, as per [Drupal Input Formats and Filters](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-input-formats-and-filters).

I am completely confused to how this is possible. Does anyone know what might cause an input filter to act so?

Comment: Identified the problem to be CKeditor. If I turn off CKeditor I no longer get the Glossary markup in nodes unless I had previously saved the node *while* CKeditor was running. Still unsure on how to resolve this problem or why it cropped up!

Comment: Ok even weirder, the problem only seems to happen in Firefox. It must be some sort of Local Cache problem...

Comment: Not a Cache problem, some how the Glossary input filter seems to be run on loading the CKeditor in the node edit form. This is putting in the Glossary markup ... Hope this helps someone else who encounters this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, somehow the Glossary filter got enabled in the CKeditor's security settings "Please choose carefully all filters that protect your content (probably not all filters listed below are security filters)."

Disabled this and now the Glossary works as it should.